# Unpack a list of dictionaries and set each to its own variable

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am creating a class which as arguments, takes 1 or more dictionaries. It then intializes a list of those dictionaries. I am defining an `__add__()` method that takes two objects of this class and returns a new object consisting of the dictionaries from the first object followed by those of the second object.

```
class DictList:
    def __init__(self, *d):
        self.dl = []
        for argument in d:
            if type(argument) != dict:
                raise AssertionError(str(argument) + ' is not a dictionary')
            if len(argument) == 0:
                raise AssertionError('Dictionary is empty')
            else:
                self.dl.append(argument)
```

For example,

```
d1 = DictList(dict(a=1,b=2), dict(b=12,c=13))  
d2 = DictList(dict(a='one',b='two'), dict(b='twelve',c='thirteen'))
```

then d1+d2 would be equivalent to

```
DictList({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 12, 'c': 13}, {'a': 'one', 'b': 'two'}, {'b': 'twelve', 'c': 'thirteen'})
```

Comment: `I am defining an add method` <- where? I don't see it

Comment: What's the question? And a small tip: you should generally avoid checking types in Python

Comment: This is just a wrapper around a list of dicts, and all you want to do is append the two lists together. It sounds like you want to do so in-place, which would be odd for `__add__` but perfectly reasonable for `__iadd__`. So just use the list `'+` or `+=` as appropriate, and it's a one-liner.

Comment: jaymmer would you mind explaining why please?

Comment: abarnett the thing is that I need to create a new class object. The parameters need to be each individual dictionary

Comment: @jaymmer ... and on the rare occasions where you do need to check types, you almost always want `isinstance`.

Comment: The big question is why you want one of these objects, which acts just like a list except with type-checked elements and a much more limited API.

Comment: PS, your description says it takes "one or more dicts", but your code takes zero or more. (And it also takes only non-empty dicts, and raises the wrong kind of exception, and uses str where it should use repr...)

Comment: OH how do i set it to take one or more arguments?

Comment: @dustinyourface: Well, you can just add an `if not d:` check if you really want that.

Answer (score 3):

To add two lists together, just use the `+` operator.

And to create one of your objects out of a list of dicts instead of a bunch of separate dict arguments, just use `*` to unpack the list.

So:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return type(self)(*(self.dl + other.dl))
```